# Make two AJAX calls. One call from form second from form created by prior AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to have to AJAX calls but using my code I can submit the first form but not the second. I have a PHP page with a form on it. This form when submitted calls another form on a modal which I would like for the modal form to make another AJAX call but with the code I am unable to do so. How can I modify my jQuery code to make this second AJAX call possible?

Javascript:

```
 $(function () {

      $('#myForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        console.log("submit");

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'assets/php/process.php',
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#message').html(obj.message);
            $('#modal').html(obj.modal);
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
          }
        }); 

        e.preventDefault();

      });

    });

    $(function () {

      $('#myForm1').on('submit', function (e) {
        console.log("submit");

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'assets/php/process.php',
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#message').html(obj.message);
            $('#modal').html(obj.modal);
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
          }
        }); 

        e.preventDefault();

      });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming logic written between the ajax call is correct you can do like this

add this is first ajax success block

```
  $('#myForm1').submit();
```

**Example:**

```
     $(function () {

      $('#myForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("submit");

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'assets/php/process.php',
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#message').html(obj.message);
            $('#modal').html(obj.modal);
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
            $('#myForm1').submit();  // calls below submit method
          }
        }); 



      });


      $('#myForm1').on('submit', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
        console.log("submit1");

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'assets/php/process.php',
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#message').html(obj.message);
            $('#modal').html(obj.modal);
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
          }
        }); 



      });

  });
```

Comment: That submits the form but I need the user to enter data into the modal before it is submitted.

Comment: 1. In the question, you haven't mentioned about "user to enter data into the modal".    2.  If user needs to fill details in 2nd form then why are you calling 2nd ajax on 1st ajax success.  It should be called when user clicks 2nd form submit button.

Comment: I apologize I thought it was assumed. I need the first call to check with the database to see if more information needs to be gathered. The modal allows the other information to be added to the database. Therefore I would like it in two separate forms.